# PhoneGap, Windows overflow divs won't scroll on drag, only on release

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-10-mobile

I have four things: mobile site, iOS app, Android app, and Windows app.

The only time this occurs is on my Windows 10 Lumia PhoneGap app. (haven't tested other windows phones)

The divs with overflow-y **do not** scroll as you drag a finger up and down. Nothing happens until your finger comes off the device, then it throws the scrollbar. So technically it scrolls, but not in a way you'd expect. It makes it impossible to slowly scroll the page up.

Windows mobile site works as expected, the divs scroll in a controlled manner with the drag of your finger. Works same everywhere else too.

Anyone run into this sort of thing? I couldn't find any user-select, -ms-overflow*, or touchmove e.preventDefault() issues in the code.